# Firebase Cloud Firestore: Managing indexes from code

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to migrate from Firebase Real time Database to Cloud Firestore in order to use "complex" queries among collections but I found some "issues" that I don't know how to solve.

My server uses Express JS and Firebase Admin SDK. I am trying to create a CRUD router for my admin dashboard but I am getting the following error:

> "9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...

When I access that URL (...) I get some error I don't have enough permissions... Well, anyway, after some research I understood that "complex" queries requires indexes and they have to be more than one.

This is my current router code so you can see what I want to achieve:

```js
// GET - Get users
router.get('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    ...
    let ref: any = db.collection('users').orderBy('createdAt');

    Object.keys(req.query).forEach(key => {
        ref = ref.where(key, '==', req.query[key]);
    });

    ...   
});
```

As you can see when I iterate `req.query` key I am adding a conditional statement to the query. My idea is to progamatically add custom filters from the client.

According to what I understood from documentation, I should create a complex index type for every document property.

Therefore, what should I do in order to achieve the mentioned idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to use that link to create exactly the index you need.  If it's not working, contact Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

Firestore compound queries have some limitations. 
One is that to use more than one method, for example "where" and "orderBy", you need to create an index for this query.

So in your case, as your queries are dynamic, for each query you will have to create an index. 
My suggestion is that you only use the "where" in your queries and in the other filters use javascript to filter. Or migrate to another database like MongoDB.

This is the link to the Firestore documentation explaining the compound queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=en-us